# Is there an iPhone/iPad library for editing fields on a table view controller?

Tags: forms, ios, uitableview, editing

I generally do the following, but I'm hoping for a library that handles this sort of editing. I couldn't find much using Google.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // [..snip..]        

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        textViewOne = [cell addSubview:[UITextView etc]];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        [textViewOne becomeFirstResponder];
        // Move UIView into view since the keyboard appears, etc.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I have only found one:

- https://github.com/elc/ELCTextFieldCell